# Send email from powershell command line with credentials

Tags: windows, email, powershell

I am trying to send an email from my gmail ccoiunt in just one single line using windows 8 and powersell. This is the code I use:

```
Send-MailMessage -smtpServer 'smtp.gmail.com' -port 587 -from 'myself@gmail.com' -to 'myself@gmail.com' -subject 'Test' -body 'Body' –UseSsl
```

But I don't know how to add the credentials. How can I add username and password to this single code line? (there is no need to encrypt the password).

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass credentials to the Send-MailMessage command for sending emails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460950/how-to-pass-credentials-to-the-send-mailmessage-command-for-sending-emails)

Comment: It is not a duplicate because "-credential $mycredentials" doesn't have the credentials in just a single code line. I don't know how to add username and password to that "-credential" command

Comment: Try reading the answers, not just the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
Send-MailMessage -smtpServer 'smtp.gmail.com' -port 587 -from 'myself@gmail.com' -to 'myself@gmail.com' -subject 'Test' -body 'Body' –UseSsl -Credential (New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "myUsername", (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "myPassword" -AsPlainText -Force))
```

Comment: Need a comma between "myUserName" and (ConvertTo-Secure -String "myPassword" -AsPlainText -Force)) since it is an ArgumentList

Comment: @quasar Good eye, thanks for catching it. I've edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
     $EmailTo = "udit043.ur@gmail.com"  // abc@domain.com
     $EmailFrom = "udit821@gmail.com"  //xyz@gmail.com
     $Subject = "zx"  //subject
     $Body = "Test Body"  //body of message
     $SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
     $filenameAndPath = "G:\abc.jpg"  //attachment
     $SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
     $attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($filenameAndPath)
     $SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)
     $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
     $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
     $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("udit821@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxx");    // xxxxxx-password
     $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```