# Email credentials when using send-mailmessage command

Tags: email, batch-file, powershell, command, powershell-2.0

I have searched through many many forums and they do explain how to do this but the technical language is just too difficult to understand as I'm very new to powershell. I would like this explained to me step by step (baby steps). I would like to run this powershell command in a batch file (.bat). I have a batch file that does robocopy backups weekly and I want the batch file to send me a email when the backup is complete. The only issue I have is the credentials, I get a pop-up box asking for the user name and password. When I eneter this information the email will send successfully. Here is what I have;

Using: powershell V2.0 Windows 7 Ultimate

```
Powershell -command send-mailmessage -to emailadress@provider.com -from emailaddress@provider.com -smtp smtp.broadband.provider.com -usessl -subject 'backup complete'
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$from = "example@mail.com" 
$to = "example@mail.com" 
$smtp = "smtpAddress.com" 
$sub = "hi" 
$body = "test mail"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "yourpassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($from, $secpasswd)
Send-MailMessage -To $to -From $from -Subject $sub -Body $body -Credential $mycreds -SmtpServer $smtp -DeliveryNotificationOption Never -BodyAsHtml
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the credential object in your same command - which would avoid the popup:

```
Powershell -Command 'Send-MailMessage -to "emailadress@provider.com" -from "emailaddress@provider.com" -smtp "smtp.broadband.provider.com" -usessl -subject "backup complete" -credential (new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("user","pass","domain"))'
```

I'd recommend storing the username/password in a somewhat more safer format, but this should do your trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do SMTP authentication using the send-mailmessage command.  But, you can send a message through an SMTP server that requires authentication using the Net.Mail.SmtpClient object and the System.Net.Mail.MailMessage object.  See [How to pass credentials to the Send-MailMessage command for sending emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460950/how-to-pass-credentials-to-the-send-mailmessage-command-for-sending-emails) for a good example.

Answer (score 0):

look at the last exemple of [send-mailmessage helppage](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/dd347693.aspx)

you will see you can pass credential whith the parameter `-credential domain01\admin01`

look here [Using PowerShell credentials without being prompted for a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239647/using-powershell-credentials-without-being-prompted-for-a-password)  if you dont want any prompt (save your cred in a text file)