# How can I use encrypted secure password in smtp credentials

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

In my .ps1 file I want to execute a job and send the result through email. I want the password to not be readable, so I encrypt it by doing this on beforehand.

```
$password = read-host -prompt "Enter your Password"
write-host "$password is password"
$secure = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -force -asPlainText
$bytes = ConvertFrom-SecureString $secure
$bytes | out-file .\securepassword.txt
```

Works just fine so far.

Then I want to use the secured password inside the .ps1, which is where I'm having difficulties. I've tried a bunch of variations, but I think this is my most solid attempt so far:

```
 $usercred = "myemail@gmail.com"
 $encryptedpw = Get-Content .\securepassword.txt
 $pwcred = $ecryptedpw | ConvertTo-SecureString
```

When I try to use this in my `$smtp.credentials` like this:

```
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($usercred, $pwcred);
```

it outputs the following error `The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.` at the `$smtp.send($msg)`

And I know the password is the issue (at least I'm pretty sure), because if I manually type it in - it works just fine. Any ideas?

**_ edit 1 _**

Below is the whole send-mail part if anyone wonder:

```
# Send Notification if alert $i is greater then 0 
if ($i -gt 0) 
{ 
    foreach ($user in $users) 
{ 

  $smtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
  $port = "587"
  $smtp.EnableSSL = $true
  $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer, $port) 
  $smtp.EnableSsl = $true 
  $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($usercred, $pwcred);
  $msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage 
  $msg.To.Add($user) 
        $msg.From = "myemail@gmail.com" 
  $msg.Subject = "Environment DiskSpace Report for $titledate" 
        $msg.IsBodyHTML = $true 
        $msg.Body = get-content $blablabla
  $smtp.Send($msg) 
        $body = "" 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: There is a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460950/how-to-pass-credentials-to-the-send-mailmessage-command-for-sending-emails and they suggest adding `$smtp.EnableSsl = $true`

Comment: Hi Micky, I have tried that as well. I'll edit the post to add the whole send-mail part. Thanks anyways!

Comment: What happens if instead of creating the NetworkCredential with a SecureString you pass it the password in plain text?

Comment: If I do for example `($usercred, "Password123")` that will work.

Comment: Why don't you use `Send-MailMessage`?

Comment: I played around with it, but I though my `$msg = new-object net.mail.mailmessage` was gonna output pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a few inputs here I was able to work out a solution. I think another factor also played a role in this.

1) I encrypted the password from another machine, which I apparently should not. I noticed the result of the encryption differentiated based on which computer that did the encryption (someone feel free to explain this one).

2) The code I ended up with was the following:

`$usercred = "myemail@gmail.com"
 $encryptedpw = Get-Content .\securepassword.txt
 $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $encryptedpw`

and then

```
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($usercred, $password);
```

Comment: SecureStrings are stored using DPAPI, which basically means it's encrypted with the user's credentials.  If you're on a different PC, you won't have the same user available (unless it's a domain user), and so won't have the necessary information to decrypt the string.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460950/how-to-pass-credentials-to-the-send-mailmessage-command-for-sending-emails) you can try the following:

```
$cred=New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, (Get-Content $FileWhereYouIsStored | ConvertTo-SecureString)
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($cred.UserName, $cred.Password);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried something similar, but this one was a bit different. However, It seems to output the same error. Weird huh?